# Should I put the version in the XSD filename?

Tags: xml, xsd, schema, version

I've read this question [Where to add a version to an XSD schema?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138705) as the closest I can find, but doesn't really help...

Is it good practice to put the version number of the schema into the filename of the XSD file?

E.g.  MyMessages_1.0.xsd

My thoughts being that if the version changes, then any dependents will need to be visited and analysed for changes, and it's very explicit which version of the schema dependents are using.

Are there any down sides to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting the version number in the filename makes it easier to pick up a specific version, and harder to write applications that automatically pick up the latest version. That's true for schemas as much as for anything else. Both policies are widely used for JAR files, for example, and I think you have to decide what works best for you on the basis of whether you want things to move forwards to new versions by default, or to stick with old versions by default.

(How I miss the VME operating system that I used in the 1970s and 80s, where aaa[123] gave you version 123 of a file, and aaa gave you the latest version).