# copyright annotations in both XSD and XML

Tags: xml, xsd, annotations, xsd-validation, xml-validation

According to [Where to put copyright information in an XSD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31651247/where-to-put-copyright-information-in-an-xsd#new-answer?newreg=425d0fc800f44715a4bdc1be3a5fb527), one way to put a copyright notice in an xsd is to insert something like

```
<xs:schema version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xsd:annotation>
  <xsd:appinfo>
    <copyright-notice>
      Copyright 2015 Example.com. All rights reserved.
    <copyright-notice>
    <license uri="http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0"
             version="2.0">Apache License, Version 2.0</license>
    <!-- ... -->
  </xsd:appinfo>
</xsd:annotation>
<!-- ... -->
</xs:schema>
```

If I do that, it works indeed.

But now, I want to insert something alike in the corresponding XML:

```
<MyCase xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="MyCaseDefinition.xsd">
<annotation>
  <appinfo>
    <copyright-notice>
      Copyright 2015 Example.com. All rights reserved.
    </copyright-notice>
    <license uri="http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0"
             version="2.0">Apache License, Version 2.0</license>
  </appinfo>
</annotation>
<!-- ... -->
</MyCase>
```

However, if I do that, I get an error:

> Invalid content starting with element 'annotation'

at the loading of the file.

It seems the 2 above are exclusive:

- If I put the annotation in the XSD, then I cannot put the equivalent in the XML.
- If I don't put anything in the XSD, then the annotation in the XML is OK.

How can I get the copyright notice in both files?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you simply forgot  a slash to close your COPYRIGHT-NOTICE tag:
try to put please

```
</copyright-notice>
```

instead of the 2nd

```
<copyright-notice>
```

tag in your xsd file.

What do you think ?

Answer (score 0):

> It seems the 2 above are exclusive:
>
> - If I put the annotation in the XSD, then I cannot put the equivalent in the XML.
> - If I don't put anything in the XSD, then the annotation in the XML is OK.

There is no such coupling:

- You can place any XML elements you or your tools would like into the XSD's `xsd:annotation/xsd:appinfo` element.
- If you wish to allow a different XML content model for any elements in your XML, you have to adjust the content model specified for such elements in your XSD.

> How can I get the copyright notice in both files?

To allow `copyright-notice` as a child of `MyCase`, add it to the content model of `MyCase` in the XSD.  You can do so with or without the shown `xsd:annotation/xsd:appinfo` heritage.  (Probably do not want it as there's no need to follow the requirements of adding `xsd:annotation/xsd:appinfo` elements to an XSD when creating your XML.)