# Different version of XSD and move into final version (remove older version) and How to handle older version namespace & request as well

Tags: xml, spring, xsd, jaxb, xml-namespaces

I have common01.xsd (namespace like http://test/common/01) and common02.xsd (namespace like http://test/common/02). Now i merged both xsd into single and come up with common.xsd(namespace like http://test/common).

Now my new request is working fine new name space (namespace like http://test/common). But in-flight payload (like store in queue & processed after deployed new code) having request with referring old xsd's namespace as well (failed). My inflight requst get failed due to namespace issue.

How to resolve this issue. I want handle all namespace with my latest common.xsd.

like similar like Spring.schemas & Spring.handler.

Any suggestion and good example to handle these case.

Comment: This is precisely why it's a bad idea to use different namespaces in different versions of the same schema.

Comment: @MichaelKay With all due respect, I disagree. Different versions with the same ns aren't less of a mess as incomatibilities are even less obvious.

Comment: This has been much discussed, see for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014237/what-are-the-best-practices-for-versioning-xml-schemas http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2004/07/21/design.html http://www.xfront.com/Versioning.pdf https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-tipnamsp/ The key thing is that if you change the namespace, then it's very hard for applications to handle both the old and the new formats simultaneously.

Comment: I wonder how spring application supporting different name space version.. i could see they are using something like spring.handler.