# xsd schema file - shows elementName is already defined

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb, xsd-validation

I have two XSD files , I want to have elements of two different xsd files with same name but with different property type.

Assume below is 
**xml1.xsd**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsd:schema
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  targetNamespace="http://www.example.com/wm"
    xmlns="http://www.example.com/wm"
  elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xsd:element name="testEame1">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>       test       </xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="id" type='xsd:string' minOccurs="1"/>
                <xsd:element name="session" type='xsd:string' minOccurs="1"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:attribute name="pid" type="xsd:integer" use="required"/>
            <xsd:attribute name="version" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

below is **xml2.xsd**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsd:schema
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  targetNamespace="http://www.example.com/wm"
    xmlns="http://www.example.com/wm"
  elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xsd:element name="testEame1">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>        test       </xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="id" type='xsd:string' minOccurs="1"/>
                <xsd:element name="session" type='xsd:integer' minOccurs="1"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:attribute name="pid" type="xsd:integer" use="required"/>
            <xsd:attribute name="version" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

There is difference of xml1 and xml2 is

> `<xsd:element name="session" type='xsd:string' minOccurs="1"/>`

and

> `<xsd:element name="session" type='xsd:integer' minOccurs="1"/>`

while running xjc with xsd files,I'm facing below issue.

```
C:\Temp\tt>xjc *.xsd
parsing a schema...
[ERROR] 'testEame1' is already defined
  line 17 of file:/C:/Temp/tt/xml2.xsd

[ERROR] (related to above error) the first definition appears here
  line 5 of file:/C:/Temp/tt/xml1.xsd

Failed to parse a schema.
```

What I visited [versioning](http://www.xfront.com/Versioning.pdf) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014237/what-are-the-best-practices-for-versioning-xml-schemas)

But I'm not sure  how to implement versioning and compile with zero errors.
Any help will be highly appreciated!

**UPDATE 1:**
**Or** I want to have session element to have type integer or string

```
<xsd:element name="session" type='xsd:integer | xsd:string' minOccurs="1"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your both schema's targetNamespace is same (http://www.example.com/wm). Once try with different targetNamespace for each schema.

Comment: thanks Umesh for the reply, I there any possible to have support for both  xsd:integer | xsd:string types ?

Comment: if you want to session element should have a value of type of string or integer, simply you can use xsd:string, this will allow both integer and string. Correct me if I am not understanding your requirement.

Comment: for illustration , I provided as an primitive type, actually it is of user defined type.I think It won't work on user defined type.