# How to import xsds of a certain version

Tags: xml, xsd

I have a question on versioning of xsd files. Lets assume that I have a xsd A that imports an xsd B. The structures specified in xsd A make use of the structures specified in xsd B and thus make the version of xsd A dependent upon the version of xsd B.

XMLs based on this would specify the namespace of xsd A and B and specify the schema location of xsd A only.

Is it possible, be it in xsd A or in the xml, to specify which version of xsd B is used, so that importing programs can determine if they are compatible with the incoming data?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the best practices for versioning XML schemas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014237/what-are-the-best-practices-for-versioning-xml-schemas)

Comment: Unfortunately it does not. The linked topic is focused on versioning of xsds in an xml. So basically one level dependency. This one is pretty well covered. But how to do this if the xsd you are using is actually dependent on another one. Like if your xsd is using dc.xsd for metadata or gml for specifying geographical data. If these dependent schemas do not manage versions by changing their namespace, how do you enable reading programs of the resulting xml to determine if they can actually properly interprete the content.